# How did Sarah understand which Kyle Reese is the T-1000 in the acid scene?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In the 'acid scene', Sarah sees two Kyle Reeses, one of which is the T-1000 (in disguise).

Both start talking in order to convince her that the other one is the T-1000, then Sarah shoots one of them in the foot.

**How did she know which one was the T-1000?**

Comment: eanie, meanie, mini, mo... one would be left without a foot, the other would regenerate. it was a 50%-50%

Comment: If I lived in a world with something that could duplicate me, I would establish a code word with my companions to say to make sure they knew who was me in exactly such a situation.

Comment: It get's better: T-1000 needs physical contact in order to mimic the other person. When this happened between T-1000 and Reese? Store, possibly, but since then Reese was roughened up considerably...

Comment: @Cherubel that should be the answer. I'm assuming if she knew for sure which was which, she wouldn't have gone with a shot to the foot. She took a guess, went for a non-fatal wound and got lucky.

Comment: A [similar](https://youtu.be/EbLtHnZ8fLc) situation occurs in *Futurama*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I watched this scene over and over, looking for "tells," but there was nothing obvious.  (For example, one of the Reeses refers to the other has "he," rather than "it," which might be more appropriate; but the one who uses "he" is actually the real one.)

The Reese that she eventually shoots is the first one to arrive, and she shoots it right after it tells her to the shoot the other.  However, neither of these would be dispositive as to whether it was real.  So I think she just went with a hunch.  The fact that she only shot it in the foot strongly suggests that she was not that confident that she was making the right decision; the real Reese could survive a shot off toe, if her hunch was in error.

Comment: Actually I'd find the use of "he" instead of correct "it" as a proof of being human: if something looks like human we tend to call it "he/she" instead of "it". It is a natural "humanization" process of something looking like human - he is a zombie, she is a ghost, he is a robot, she is an alien. Machine would use the correct "it".

Comment: Thanks, it is a bad scripted movie, but you don't expect it to be this bad.